# how to update git clone?

Tags: git, clone

I have a clone of a branch from git repo.
I made changes commited and pushed to remote branch.
Now I want to update my clone to remote branch, so that changes made by anybody else should appear in my clone.
How to do that ?
Thanks

Comment: https://githowto.com/

Comment: Use either `git pull origin branch_name` or `git pull --rebase origin branch_name`.  You may get conflicts if you have made commits since you last pulled.

Comment: Also consider reading the wonderful Git Book : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*git pull* will retrieve remote modification and merge it to your worktree.

If you only want to view remote changes,

> git fetch

will retrieve remote changes to local, and you can refer it by origin/branch_name.